# Tips for page navigation for a new web programmer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have now been working as a web developer for two weeks and have written my first page connected it to database have everything setup the way I want and now my next big hurdle. I want to get to this page from another page. the second page emulates written forms and the first page will have a grid of the submitted forms. Looking through the net I have found Iframes and there are a couple of other options I am still reading up about, but i wanted to pose the question here as well. What is the generally accepted / good practice method for navigating from page to page in asp.net. Going from database to web has been a trip but its one i am enjoying.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response.Redirect("Default1.aspx"):

- we want to redirect the request to some plain HTML pages on our server or to some other web server
- we don't care about causing additional roundtrips to the server on each request
- we do not need to preserve Query String and Form Variables from the original request
- we want our users to be able to see the new redirected URL where he is redirected in his browser (and be able to bookmark it if its necessary)

Server.Transfer("Default1.aspx") :

- we want to transfer current page request to another .aspx page on the same server
- we want to preserve server resources and avoid the unnecessary roundtrips to the server
- we want to preserve Query String and Form Variables (optionally)
- we don't need to show the real URL where we redirected the request in the users Web Browser

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to simply redirect the user you could use `Response.Redirect(url)`, this will redirect the user to the specified relative page. For example, if you were in `Page1.aspx` and wanted to redirect to `Page2.aspx` you would simply write

```
Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx");
```

Please keep in mind, this is a very simple approach to redirecting, and information submitted from Page1 to Page2 won't get persisted, so you'll need to either save these in the database, or in the session.

Hope this helps a bit. :)

*Edit*

Reading your question further; if you wanted to load a form after selecting it in Page1, you would want to somehow pass it  through to Page2. The easiest way would be to append it to the query string, and then check if the query string value exists on Page2 loads.

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate to another page using

```
Response.Transfer("Default2.aspx");
```

Else you can use

```
Server.Transfer("Default.aspx")
```

but it is bulky since it transfer that data of previous page too..

Answer (score 2):

Response.Redirect does the job of navigating from one page to another. Below is good article which explains the correct use of it, hope this helps.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx